# Wordpress image gallery thumbnail grid - click to view more

Tags: php, html, wordpress, gallery, thumbnails

I am working on a custom portfolio template page to display all posts with a gallery. Since some of the galleries have many images, I want to collapse them to minimize page scrolling.

What is the best way to display the first row of thumbnails in the grid, on page load, then click a "load more" button to display the remaining thumbnails?

I'm trying to follow WP's get_post_gallery() function, but not sure how to tell it to load only the first few thumbnails, then click to load more. If I can somehow utilize Bootstrap 3's collapse/expand code, that would be great since I'm using that framework on the website.

Included a mockup of what I am trying to achieve:
[View Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or5Hz.png)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery

```html
<?php
    /* The loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
            $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
            
            /* Loop through all the image and output them one by one */
            foreach( $gallery['src'] as $src ) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="my-custom-class" alt="Gallery image" />
                <?php
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get your gallery with the $data parameter to true, you can cycle through the array and use the bootstrap show/hide the usual way!

```
$return_array = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), true);
```

this will return an array, that array will have that structure

```
  'link' => string 'file' 
  'ids' => string 'id1,id2,id3' 
  'src' => 
    array 
      0 => string 'http://yoursite/moo.jpg'
      2 => string 'http://yoursite/moo2.jpg' 
      3 => string 'http://yoursite/moo3.jpg'
```

if you are going to use the permalink, you split the string for ids into another array with

```
$ids_Array = explode(',',return_array["ids"]);
```

you can then loop that array and build your bootstrap's collapse structure the way you want (after 3 loops you output the delimiting container, etc)

if you have any questions let me know!

Comment: Ralph, thanks for your quick reply! I will try this today and follow up.

Comment: I tried a few things with your suggestion but I haven't gotten it yet. PHP is still new to me so there are some obvious things I may be overlooking to connect the dots.